# ImpropertyConfigured issues with customized password valiators in django

Tags: python, django, validation, passwords, customization

I´m writing customised password validators for django. But I get ImproperlyConfigured error ->

*ImproperlyConfigured
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The module in NAME could not be imported: auth.validators.UppercaseValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.*

**settings.py**        (path : app/conf/settings/settings.py).      ->

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator', 'OPTIONS': {'min_length': 12}},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'auth.validators.UppercaseValidator'},
]
```

**validators.py**         (path: app/auth/validators.py).     ->

```
import re

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class UppercaseValidator(object):
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z."),
                code='password_no_upper',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _("Your password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z.")
```

I'm started to get a bit crazy because I cant see what the problem is
pliz help me

Comment: try change your app name `auth` by `custom_auth` for example. I think I remember that you can't have an app with the name Auth because it conflicts with Django's own Auth app.

Comment: I tried to move validators.py to the same folder as settings.py but had the same issue  (app/conf/settings/)

Comment: Try change `if not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):` to `if not len(re.findall('[A-Z]', password)) >= 1:`

Comment: Or try change `'app.auth.validators.UppercaseValidator'`